# Built-in microphone is not detected

Tags: sound, alsa, microphone

After updating the ubuntu 20.04, the audio I/O devices are not detected. (I had only dummy output).
The built-in speaker detected after adding the following lines to `Alsa config`:

```
options snd-hda-intel model=auto
options snd-hda-intel dmic_detect=0
```

But the microphone is not detected anymore. (I've seen other people also have the same problem by this fix).

There is no capture device in alsamixer:
[image]

And this is the Settings > Sound:
[image]

Appreciate any help.

OS: ubuntu 20.04
Laptop: Lenovo Thinkpad p14s G2